# Python 3: Print the average of the test scores in a file that has letter and numbers

Tags: python-3.x, file

I apologize ahead of time if I'm doing something wrong since I am new to programming...

In my CS class they are asking for a interface which allows the user to creates files which have the assignment name and grade. I was able to write the create files function, but I am having difficulties with another function which is asked for in the project. In this function, it asks to open the .txt file, print what is in the .txt file, print the total amount of assignments in the file after all assignments have read, print the average grade for all assignments, and print the letter grade. This is what I have so far but it doesn't work at all:

```
    try:
        sms=[]
        with open(fileName, "r") as f:
            print(f.read())  # prints grades
            for line in f:
                numbers = line.split('\n')  # split the scores form the text
                s=0
                for number in numbers:
                    try:
                        s=+int(number)
                    except:
                        print('cant cast int')
                sms.append(s)
            average=sum(sms)/len(fileName)
            avg='F'
            if average>= 90:
                avg='A'
            if average>= 80:
                avg='B'
            if average>= 70:
                avg='C'
            if average>= 60:
                avg='D'
            print('Average grade: '+str(average))
            print('Letter grade assigned: '+str(avg))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('**Error: This file cannot be found**')
        processmenu()
```

The try statement is required. And the processmenu() restarts it. How do I isolate the txt file, or more specifically grade number (ie.12.0, 56.0 etc), and make/print a avg
This is what the text files look like, the length of them depends on the users input when creating the file, so there could be 20+ assignments.

```html
Assignment 1:      12.0
Assignment 2:      56.0
Assignment 3:      76.0
```

Comment: Once you read the content of an open file with `f.read()`, you cannot read it again. The loop `for line in f` does not make any iterations.

Comment: Yes, delete the `print(f.read())` and just print the lines individually in your loop.

Comment: @TimRoberts How would I do that? especially considering the .txt could be any length. I apologize I am a complete newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take note that this solution requires python 3.6 or above to retain dictionary order since it uses a dictionary.

Output:

```
Total number of assignments in file: 12

Grade for individual assignment:
Assignment 1 : 12.0 : F
Assignment 2 : 56.0 : F
Assignment 3 : 76.0 : C
Assignment 4 : 13.0 : F
Assignment 5 : 59.0 : F
Assignment 6 : 78.0 : C
Assignment 7 : 14.0 : F
Assignment 8 : 58.0 : F
Assignment 9 : 79.0 : C
Assignment 10 : 15.0 : F
Assignment 11 : 57.0 : F
Assignment 12 : 80.0 : B

Average grade for all assignments:
All assignments : 49.75 : F
```

Code:

```
import re
from decimal import Decimal

file_name = "results.txt"


with open(file_name) as file_in:
    lines = []
    for line in file_in:
        if re.match(r"^Assignment\s\d+:\s+\d+\.\d+$", line):
            lines.append(line)

def retProper(temp4):
    global lines
    temp5 = -1
    for temp6 in range(len(lines)):
        temp7 = len(lines[temp6].split(":")[1].strip().split(".")[1])
        if temp7 > temp5:
            temp5 = temp7
    return round(Decimal(temp4),temp5)

grade_threshold = {retProper(0):"F", retProper(60):"D", retProper(70):"C", retProper(80):"B", retProper(90):"A"}

def getGradeLetter(temp2):
    global grade_threshold
    temp3 = list(grade_threshold)[0]
    for key, elem in grade_threshold.items():
        if (temp2 >= key):
            temp3 = key
    return grade_threshold.get(temp3)

print("Total number of assignments in file: "+str(len(lines)))
print("\nGrade for individual assignment:")

for temp1 in range(len(lines)):
    exec('print(lines[temp1].split(":")[0]+" : "+lines[temp1].split(":")[1].strip()+" : "+getGradeLetter(retProper('+lines[temp1].split(":")[1].strip()+')))')

print("\nAverage grade for all assignments:")
temp10 = []
for temp8 in range(len(lines)):
    exec("temp9 = retProper("+lines[temp8].split(':')[1].strip()+")")
    temp10.append(temp9)

temp12 = retProper(0)
for temp11 in range(len(temp10)):
    temp12 = temp12 + temp10[temp11]
average_grade_number = (temp12/len(temp10))
print("All assignments : "+str(average_grade_number)+" : "+getGradeLetter(average_grade_number))
```

Comment: replaced "results.txt" with the variable fileName because it depends on the users input which is ask for earlier, but it gave me: "NameError: name 'lines' is not defined". it also says temp 9 is an unresolved reference. BTW I REALLY appreciate you taking the time to write this, I don't know how my professor expects a newbie to write something like this.

Comment: strange, because the code works perfectly for me as can be seen from the output i posted above............. if temp9 has an error........ where are you running the code? what is the OS? what is the python version?

Comment: python 3.9 / windows 10 / pycharm, running it in a function (that might be why buts its required for my assignment), the instructor also wants us to include a try/except statement(my apologies for not mentioning that). I really appreciate your help and apologize for any mistakes( I have no idea what I'm doing lol)

Comment: @AydenCabral I want to help but it is limited what I can do if I can't see your screen. If you have a screen-sharing app like zoom which also allows remote control, that'd be easier.

Comment: Would you be down to join a zoom in 10 mins?

Comment: @AydenCabral roger

Comment: roger roger    https://us04web.zoom.us/j/73385205442?pwd=OE1RMUpsWUZueFJmbXIrK0Q0emhaQT09